# Running background task when user stops using app and moved to another in Metro app

Tags: microsoft-metro

Hello I am having below requirement in my metro app. Can you please explain how to handle this?

1. User logged in to app by entering his login credentails.
2. Then user moved to another app and started working on it(still he is using machine).
3. He came back after 15 Min. Now, I have to throw error message say "Session Tiemout"

I tried using BackgroungTask - but not succeeded. Reason is I cant initiate background task OnSuspend().

Let me know how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the notification to happen when the app is activated again, then simply register the [App Activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx#app_activation) handler and check to see if your login has timed out.

If you want the notification to happen outside of your app you will need to use a [toast notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779727.aspx) with a [scheduled notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779721.aspx).

Background tasks are for doing work in the background while the user is doing something else.  It can't be used for notifications.